# Creating permutations incrementally where elements are presented evenly and distributed uniformly

Tags: python, permutation

***EDIT: I figured this out. See solution at the end. I would be very interested to see if there are more efficient implementations (there surely are).***

I need to create multiple arrays with 9 elements each using numbers 0-11 (inclusive). Numbers need to be sampled randomly and stored in aleatory order. Let's assume these arrays will themselves be stored in an array. This resulting array needs to satisfy two requirements regardless of the number of arrays it contains (above a certain threshold, of course):

1. Numbers 0-11 need to be sampled evenly across all arrays
2. Each number needs to be indexed uniformly across all arrays (e.g. be `index[0]` roughly the same number of times as it is `index[1]` and `index[2]` ... and `index[11]`.
3. (1) and (2) need to hold true for any portion of the resulting array. I.e. `resulting_array[0:100]` as well as `resulting_array[200:300]` and so forth.

So far, I have tried using itertools and shuffle. This approach produces a more or less even count for all numbers even if I slice a small part of the resulting array (it could be better in this regard, though). However, it doesn't make numbers be distributed evenly across array indices. Also, this produces way more permutations than I need; I estimate with 500 hundred permutations I should be fine.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict as d

# create 10 random arrays to get things going
def shuffleThings(num, arr):
    results = []
    for i in range(num):
        b = arr.copy()
        random.shuffle(b)
        a = b[0:arrSize]
        results.append(a)
    return results

def updateDict(fDict, dDict, arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):       
        fDict[arr[i]] += 1
        dDict[arr[i]][i] += 1    
        
def pickNums(arr):
    selected = []
    #random.shuffle(arr)
    for i in range(arrSize):
        selected.append(arr[i][0])
    random.shuffle(selected)
    return selected

def sortArrays(list1, list2): 
    zipped_pairs = zip(list2, list1) 
    z = [x for _, x in sorted(zipped_pairs)]     
    return z
    

startArrays = 10
totalArrays = 80
nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
arrSize = 9
freqDict = d(list)
distDict = d(list)

for i in nums:
    freqDict[i] = 0
    distDict[i] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
all_arrays = shuffleThings(10, nums)
for i in all_arrays:
    updateDict(freqDict, distDict,i)

for i in range(totalArrays - startArrays):
    f = sorted(freqDict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
    tempNums = pickNums(f)
    newNums = ["","","","","","","","",""]
    counter = 0
    for j in tempNums:
        dists = distDict[j]
        indices = sortArrays([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],dists)
        for k in indices:
            if (newNums[k]==""):
                newNums[k] = j
                break
        counter += 1
    updateDict(freqDict,distDict,newNums)
    all_arrays.append(newNums)
    
res = []
for i in range(len(all_arrays)):
    res.append(str(all_arrays[i])[1:-1])

print(*res, sep='\n')
>>>
##excerpt
1, 3, 0, 8, 5, 7, 9, 11, 10
6, 2, 0, 1, 8, 7, 11, 5, 10
2, 5, 10, 0, 1, 9, 7, 8, 3
4, 9, 3, 7, 1, 5, 8, 11, 2
10, 0, 5, 8, 4, 9, 1, 2, 7
5, 2, 9, 8, 7, 0, 10, 4, 11
2, 0, 7, 10, 5, 4, 1, 3, 8
2, 9, 4, 0, 1, 3, 10, 6, 8
3, 0, 1, 9, 4, 10, 5, 11, 2
1, 5, 2, 7, 0, 8, 10, 11, 9
11, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 7, 9, 0

print(freqDict)
>>> {0: 60, 1: 60, 2: 60, 3: 60, 4: 60, 5: 60, 6: 60, 7: 60, 8: 60, 9: 60, 10: 60, 11: 60}

print(distDict)
>>> {0: [7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7], 
1: [7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 6, 6], 
2: [6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6], 
3: [7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7], 
4: [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7], 
5: [6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6], 
6: [6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8], 
7: [7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6], 
8: [6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7], 
9: [7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 7], 
10: [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6], 
11: [7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7]}
```

Comment: if you sample from a uniform distribution and do not have a unicity requirement across columns / rows, you should just pick the numbers randomly and make them in the shape you need. That should be enough. On the other hand, if you need unicity across rows/columns perhaps you could look into cyclic permutations instead of full permutations.

Comment: Because of what I am doing in Qualtrics, I need to make sure numbers are distributed uniformly across indices, which random sampling doesn't guarantee. For an array [8, 0, 9, 3, 7, 11, 5, 10, 2], each number controls one variable (X) of my stimuli, and the position of the number in the array controls a second variable (Y). Numbers on indices 0-2 determine what X is combined with Y, such that this array would produce Y0_X8, Y0_X0, Y0_X9. Indices 3-5 would produce Y1_X3, Y1_X7, Y1_X11. Indices 6-8 would produce Y2_X5, Y2_X10, Y2_X2. I need all Y and X combinations to be selected equal n of times

Comment: I will look into cyclic permutations, though. Thank you

Comment: It looks a relatively convoluted reasoning. Why not making those relationships a bit more explicit?